# Nestjs import dependecy not working to import my service

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I import a module in other module but a can access the service in other context

The module when i exported

```js
@Module({
  controllers: [ModuleController],
  providers: [
    ModulesAcessService,
    ModulesRepository,
    ModulesService
  ],
  exports: [ModulesService, ModulesRepository, ModulesAcessService],
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ModuleEntity]),
    forwardRef(() => CoursesModule),
    forwardRef(() => LessonsModule)
  ]
})
export class ModulesModule { }
```

The module when i imported - ModulesModule

```js
@Module({
  controllers: [LessonsController],
  providers: [
    LessonsService,
    LessonsAcessService,
    LessonsRepository,
    UserLessonsService,
    UserLessonsRepository,
    UserLessonsSubscriber,
    UserLessonsEvents
  ],
  exports: [LessonsRepository,LessonsService, LessonsAcessService, UserLessonsService],
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Lesson, UserLesson]),
    forwardRef(() => CoursesModule),
    forwardRef(() => ModulesModule)
  ]
})
export class LessonsModule { }
```

The error message

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the LessonsService (LessonsAcessService, UserLessonsService, UrlHelper, LessonsRepository, CoursesService, ?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [5] is available in the LessonsModule context.
```

The import in my service - I can't access the ModulesService.

```js
import { ModulesService } from '../modules/modules.service';

@Injectable()
export class LessonsService {

  constructor(
    private lessonsAccessService: LessonsAcessService,
    private userLessonsService: UserLessonsService,
    private urlHelper: UrlHelper,
    private lessonsRepository: LessonsRepository,
    private coursesService: CoursesService,
    private modulesService: ModulesService
  ) { }
...
```

---

- Node version 14.7.0
- Nestjs version 7

Comment: Does your `ModulesService` import your `LessonsService`?

Comment: yes, i import the LessonsService in ModulesService to use.

Comment: have you tried this: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency#forward-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of the `forwardRef` for the services too, not just the modules. In your `ModulesService` use `@Inject(forwardRef(() => LessonsService))` on the `lessonsService`. In the `LessonsService` use `@Inject(forwardRef(() => ModulesService))` on the `modulesService`.